# preimages of morphisms of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes

So I have (again) a question regarding sheaves and their properties. Specifically, I have a problem with understanding a certain statement of the following proof:
[image]

[image]

Just for completeness, I added the full proof. I dont understand how to take preimages of maps of sheaves and why we are able to refine that cover even further. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the parenthetical "simply by refining...". It looks $j : S \to X$ is a map of schemes, not a map of sheaves. The idea then is that, since $X$ is covered by $X_i$, we have that $S$ is covered by $j^{-1}(X_i)$. We can choose a cover of $S$ by affine opens by choosing a cover of each $j^{-1}(X)$ by affine opens $S_j$ and taking the union of those.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i meant schemes. And yeah thats what i figured, but how does one even form the preimage of an affine scheme, i.e. how are preimages of locally ringed spaces formed. did you mean X_i in the end?

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, I believe @Vector's answer is what you need. The point is that if $(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ is a locally ringed space and $W \subseteq Y$ is an open subset, then $W$ can be equipped with a canonical structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_Y|W$. We then interpret preimages in this case as "preimage at the level of underlying topological spaces, but equipped with the canonical structure of a locally ringed space". Also yes, I did mean $X_i$ in my last comment.

Comment: Okay i understand what you mean on the level of topological spaces, but what do we do on the level of sheafs, i.e. if we have a morphism of ringed spaces (f,f*) from lets say X to Y, how does the preimage look like? It is maybe a stupid question but i have to wrap my head around it somehow.

Comment: Every open subset $W$ of a (locally ringed) space $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ can be canonically made into a (locally ringed) space using the restricted structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_Y|_W$. In this case, if $W\subseteq Y$ is an open subset, the  $f^{-1}(W)$ is an open subset of $X$. All together, given a map $(f, \phi) : (X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to (Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$, the preimage (as locally ringed spaces) of an open subset $W\subseteq Y$ is $(f^{-1}(W), \mathcal{O}_X |_{f^{-1}(W)})$.

Comment: Hmm okay that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your questions. I think you may want find a cover of $S$? We can just give a topological cover of $X$ first, and for any cover $X_i$, we get a topological preimage $f^-1(X_i)$ and find the cover $S_j$. And we give $S_j$ the open subscheme structure, and $S_j$ will factor through $X_i$ (as topological map), finally by Exercise 2.2.12 of Qing Liu's 'Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curve', we know this can become a ringed space morphism.

Comment: If you're not sure if you understand a question, ask in a comment for clarification.  Starting an answer with a declaration of your uncertainty, means you don't understand.

Comment: okay got it but we need it to factor through the X_i as a ringed space or am i wrong?

Comment: @amWhy I dont have enough reputation to post a comment

Comment: @TammoBrinner As I said, just factor through as a topological space, the left is the exercise 2.2.12

Comment: okay thank you !